# Can't create macro with Deathwish and Blood Fury

Tags: world-of-warcraft-classic

I want to make a macro that casts `Deathwish` and `Blood Fury`at the same time or after another.

I did the following
`/castsequence Deathwish, Blood Fury` but it only does execute the first in the array. If I switch them then only Blood Fury is executed.

However

```
/use Blood Rage
/cast Berserker Rage
```

does work fine (tried the same with the above).

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Silly point: did you spell it as `Death Wish` or `Deathwish`? Because that's where (part of) your problem might be. Your `castsequence` macro should work fine if you spell it as Death Wish. An easy way to see: if the icon displayed is a red question mark, the game doesn't recognize the spell you are trying to cast.

Comment: I am playing the german version and triple checked the names

Comment: Ah, that rules it out then. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: A castsequence macro requires you to press the macro once for each spell in the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I know I'm a bit late to this thread, but as no correct information was posted I will clarify a few things.

Blood Fury is **ON** the Global Cooldown, but does **not Trigger** the global cooldown. This means if you cast Blood Fury **FIRST** it allows an instant Death Wish (or any other ability on the GCD).

This means a macro that takes this into account will indeed let you use both at the same time (by spamming the button a bit).

Here is an example of a Blood Fury + Death Wish macro that allows you to use both + just Death Wish or Blood Fury depending on cooldowns:

```
#showtooltip Death Wish
/use 13
/castsequence reset=5 Blood Fury, Death Wish
/cast Death Wish
```

Be sure you are not on the Global Cooldown when you use this macro.

Answer (score 3):

You've run afoul of the [Global Cooldown, or GCD](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Cooldown#Global_cooldown). Both [Death Wish](https://classic.wowhead.com/spell=12328/death-wish) and [Blood Fury](https://classic.wowhead.com/spell=20572/blood-fury) trigger the GCD, so your macro casts the first one, then immediately attempts to cast the second, but can't, because you're in a 1.5 second GCD. [Bloodrage](https://classic.wowhead.com/spell=2687/bloodrage) *doesn't* trigger the GCD, which is why your macros including it work.

There's just no way to cast Death Wish and Blood Fury less that 1.5 seconds apart. The /castsequence macro lets you press a key to cast the first spell, and then press the same key to cast the second spell AFTER the GCD has expired. Beware that macros only work one way; macros can't pull information from the game, they can only send commands. If you spam your macro, it will keep alternating between the spells every time you press the key, as if you were alternatively spamming two keys on your keyboard.

Comment: To add to this: if you make a macro with `/cast Death Wish` and `/cast Blood Fury`, you'd have a "spammable" button that casts `Death Wish` if it's up, or `Blood Fury` when Death Wish is on cooldown, but Blood Fury is up. The only downside to this button is that it will only display the `Death Wish` icon and tooltip on your bars.

Comment: @IvoCoumans Which can be negated via #showtooltip

Comment: @IvoCoumans That doesn't work. When Death Wish is on CD, if you run that macro it says "Ability is not ready". It does not cast Blood Fury.